# Universal group of graph of groups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

I am reading Scott and Wall's paper on Topological Methods on Group Theory.

At one place he mentions: universal group of graph of groups. What is the meaning of this. In particular, I am attaching the proof that I am unable to understand:

[image: Theorem]

[image]

[image]

I am having trouble with the converse.

Comment: A quick look at the article entails me to say it is a typo and the authors probably mean "fundamental group of the graph of groups", whose construction is recalled in the beginning.

Comment: Yes. That is what I am thinking. But then G is the fundamental group of the graph of groups G\Y whether or not (i) and (ii) hold. 

Also, he uses 'universal group' twice (in first and second line). That is what making me uneasy.

Comment: Your assertation about "whether or not (i) ad (ii) hold" is false. If (i) and (ii) do not hold then $G$ is not the fundamental group of $G\setminus Y$. This is because $G$ is only the fundamental group of $G\setminus Y$ if the action of $G$ on $Y$ is proper; that is, if there is no global fixed point; that ism if $G$ does not have FA.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more? Why is it so that G is the fundamental group of G\Y if the action of G on Y is proper?

Comment: Handwavingly, $\pi_1(X)$ acts properly and cocomplactly on $\widetilde{X}$. Here, the tree $Y$ plays the role of $\widetilde{X}$ and $G\setminus Y$ plays the role of $X$. So you need the action to be proper; you need no global foxed points. However, this is handwavey as we cannot just throw around words like "fundamental group" and hope analogies work! In our case, it is *more* than an analogy - there is a paper of Bass where he defines a topology on a graph of groups $X$ such that $G=\pi_1(X)$ and were $\widetilde{X}$ is the Bass-Serre tree - the analogy is more than just an analogy!

Comment: More concretely - every group $G$ acts on a tree with global fixed point: take a rooted tree with $|G|$ children, each child labelled by an element of $G$. Then $G$ acts on this tree by left multiplication of the labels. However, the root is fixed. The key observation is that this is, in a certain sense, the *only* obstruction to Bass-Serre theory working. That is, if $G$ does not have FA then either $G$ maps on to the infinite cyclic group or $G$ splits as a free product with amalgamation.

Comment: (some aspects of the above comments are incorrect...)